# Associate file type/extension to non document based cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, file-type, associate

This is for some reason really hard to find and solve. Cannot find any documentation on it.
I've got a non-document based application which I would like to open all specific file types, but I do not want to use NSDocuments but let my code handle the opening of file and processing of it. I've added the CFBundleTypeExtensions and all, settings to the info.plist.

Now the application will open the filetype but display an error like: "The document xxxx could not be opened. Application cannot open files in the yyyyy format."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you implemented [-application:openFile:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008592-CH1-SW29) in an app delegate? If not, your application has no way of knowing how to open some random file in some random format. It's up to you to add that functionality and respond with success or failure.

Comment: Sorry, I meant something else.
When a user double clicks on an file extension (configured in CFBundleTypeExtensions) my app should handle the request correctly. But without usage of NSDocument.

Comment: You said your app will open (I assume when double-clicking the file) but will complain the document couldn't be opened. In a non-document-based app, this requires you to have an object serve as Application delegate and answer to -application:openFile: to do the right thing. Have you done this?

Comment: Ahh, it was really that simple indeed. This is the answer. I was completely looking at the wrong place. Thanks.